# trying to change the counter color in javascript

Tags: javascript

i m trying to change color of counter when it reached th limit 
but its not working . dont know why
im new to javascrit , i dont know about jquery , please asnwer in javascript.
here is my code work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function counting(){
    var count = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    var grab = document.getElementById('text1');
    var count1 = document.getElementById('p1');
    count1.innerHTML = count.length;

    if (grab.length > 10) {
       count1.style.color="#0033bb";
    };
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<textarea id="text1" onkeyup="counting();"></textarea>
<p id="p1">0</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your testing `grab.length` when you should be testing `count.length`.

Comment: i tryd but its not working

Comment: check the if condition is working by alerting a text inside the if condition. Also remove the ; after if

Comment: @javascripto: [it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/09pL308g/). (I changed color to something more visible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grab is element, instead you want its value

```
if (grab.value.length > 10) {
   count1.style.color="red";
}
```

working fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/entw1e39/

As others are pointing out you can also use

```
 if (count.length > 10) {
     count1.style.color="red";
 }
```

but then i would rewrite

```
var grab = document.getElementById('text1');
var count = grab.value;
```

It is a good practice. There is no need to call DOM two times, it is cost inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

`grab` is the input element, and `grab.length` is always `undefined`.

You may use `count.length` instead of `grab.length`.